# Passing a click action for preview in android jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-preview

**What I have** :

- I have a compose class that has a button
- I want to see the preview in the design view

**Issue I am facing** :

- For the click How to pass as an object on the line I have marked in
  code

***Is this possible ?***

**`OnBoardingActionButton.kt`**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun OnBoardingActionButton(
    modifier : Modifier,
    pagerState: PagerState,
    onClick : () -> Unit
){
    OnBoardingActionButtonContent(pagerState,onClick)
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun OnBoardingActionButtonContent(pagerState: PagerState, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.padding( horizontal = 40.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        AnimatedVisibility(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            visible = true
        ) {
            Button(onClick = onccl) {

            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PrevOnBoardingActionButton(){
    val pagerState : PagerState = PagerState(2)
    val  onClick : () -> Unit  -----------------------------> How to manage this
    OnBoardingActionButtonContent(pagerState, onClick)
}
```

**Error**:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PrevOnBoardingActionButton(){
    val pagerState : PagerState = PagerState(2)
    val  onClick : () -> Unit = {}
    OnBoardingActionButtonContent(pagerState, onClick)
}
```